# Stardog Connection.commit() raising java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Tags: java, stardog

I am trying to add statements to a stardog connection using a connection pool. For some reason about halfway through data ingest, I get a ClosedChannelConnectionException when I try to commit.

```
// This all runs in a loop
while ... {
  def conn = connPool.obtain()
  conn.begin()

  // Add some statements here
  conn.add()...

  conn.commit() // This line throws the exception

  connPool.release(conn)
}
```

The exception is:

```
com.complexible.stardog.StardogException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

After the exception, the stardog server crashes, but there are no errors in the logs. When I restart the server, the database I was using is offline and I have to recreate it to use it.

I am using Stardog 2.1 Community Edition.

Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Bug in stardog. That exception means something  in this JVM has closed the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running an in-memory database and the server was crashing because the machine ran out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `ChannelClosedException` is a bit of a red herring; if the server is going down, that's why the channel is closed.

Why not simply bring the database back online rather than re-creating it?  Does the error happen with the same data each time?

I recommend you post this on the Stardog mailing list with a complete example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: ChannelClosedException means that *this JVM* closed the channel. Not the peer. It might be an indication that the server is 'going down' or it might not.

Comment: I'm aware of what the exception means; I'm telling the OP why it happened.

Comment: I did try to bring the database back online, but I had problems doing that. When I restart the server, the log says: `SEVERE: Database test will not be available because there was an error initializing the database: null`. When I run `stardog-admin db list` test is indeed there. When I run `stardog-admin db test online` it says `The database test is already online`. When I go to localhost:5820/test it says the database is _not_ online. Is there any way to recover other than drop and recreate? Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you post this to the Stardog mailing list, the comments on SO are not an effective way to troubleshoot your issue.